# How to navigate back main page gpicontroller task use other machine

Tags: uwp, gpio

Pleas explain where can we put in program.

```
NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
Frame.navigate(typeof(otherpage));
```

Comment: Clarify your question and title.

Comment: What did you mean about 'gpicontroller task use other machine
'? Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the `otherpage` XAML

```
<Page
    NavigationCacheMode="Required"
    ...
    />
```

or in the constructor in the code behind

```
NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

See an old Silverlight example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.navigationcachemode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?#Examples

Comment: System.IO.FileLoadException: 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: I done as your adviced but when after goback MainPage GpioController getting that message:

Answer (score 0):

Just add in MainPage XAML that's all enough. Also Gpio controller problem.

NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"